# VIM help in understanding X123X

Tags: vim

I came across very helpful mapping for VIM in [vim Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Easily_switch_between_source_and_header_file)

The mapping says:

```
map <F4> :e %:p:s,.h$,.X123X,:s,.cpp$,.h,:s,.X123X$,.cpp,<CR>
```

I wanted to expand it - For example cc/h files

But I couldn't understand the script. Mainly the X123X

Following pattern, I just did this:

```
map <F4> :e %:p:s,.h$,.X123X,:s,.cpp$,.h,:s,.X123X$,.cpp,:s,.cc$,.h,:s,.X123X$,.cc,<CR>
```

Now, it maps .CC->.H but not from .H->.CC instead it maps .H->.CPP.

Can any one help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This mapping uses the special `:s` filename modifier (`:help filename-modifiers`) to swap the file extensions.

Because all substitutions are executed sequentially, the `.h` extension is first transformed into the `.X123X` placeholder value, so that the following `.cpp` → `.h` transformation doesn't apply to it.

This trick works well for a single pair; if you want to add alternatives, I would rather switch to a Vim function that does the swapping.

```
function! SwappedExtension()
    let [rest, ext] = [expand('%:r'), expand('%:e')]
    if ext ==? 'h'
        let ext = 'cpp'
    elseif ext ==? 'cpp'
        let ext = 'h'
    endif
    return rest . '.' . ext
endfunction
:nnoremap <F4> :e <C-r><C-r>SwappedExtension()<CR><CR>
```

Also, there are plugins that do this, e.g. the [a.vim - Alternate Files quickly (.c --> .h etc)](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=31).